# How can i store the url of the image instead of path of the image in firestore flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to store the URL of the image like this -

[this is how i want to store url of the image in firestore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLPWo.png)

This is my current condition -

[Currently it's showing the path of the image not the url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNZTt.png)

```
   onPressed: () async {
          if (imageFile == null) {
            print("error");
          } else {
            try {
              final ref = storage
                  .ref()
                  .child('user_profile_images')
                  .child(name + '.jpg');
              ref.putFile(imageFile!);
              url = await ref.getDownloadURL();
              if (url != null) {
                print(url);
              }
            } catch (e) {
              print(e);
            }

            dynamic user = await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                email: email, password: password);
            await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection('users')
                .doc(name)
                .set({
              'email': email,
              'name': name,
              'profileurl': imageFile?.path,
              'userid': auth.currentUser?.uid
            }).then((value) {
              try {
                if (user != null) {
                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/dashboard');
                }
              } catch (e) {
                print(e);
              }
            });
          }
        }),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a feeling the multiple `try`/`catch` blocks are getting in your way. In addition, it is never a good idea to mix `then` and `await` in a single block of code.

Combining those, try the following:

```
try {
  final ref = storage
      .ref()
      .child('user_profile_images')
      .child(name + '.jpg');
  ref.putFile(imageFile!);
  url = await ref.getDownloadURL();
  if (url != null) {
    print(url);
  }

  dynamic user = await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
    email: email, password: password);
  dynamic value = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('users')
    .doc(name)
    .set({
      'email': email,
      'name': name,
      'profileurl': url // 
      'userid': auth.currentUser?.uid
    });
  if (user != null) {
      Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/dashboard');
  }
} catch (e) {
  print(e);
}
```

Comment: well, it still shows "/data/user/0/com.example.hangout_project/cache/scaled_image_picker8512681373412994610.jpg" in the field of profile url in firestore instead of the url containing "https://"

Comment: That seems much simpler: you should write `url` to the database. I updated the code in my answer to show that.

Answer (score 0):

`'profileurl': imageFile?.path,` => `'profileurl': url?.toString(),`

Comment: tried it already, then it shows "null" in the profileurl field in firestore